# JavaScript dictionary, What does [dictionary_name].[something] mean?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, dictionary, backend

In the code below, what does audioLanguageDict.id, audioLanguageDict.text mean?

```
AudioLanguage.createFromDict = function(audioLanguageDict) {
return new AudioLanguage(
  audioLanguageDict.id,
  audioLanguageDict.text,
  audioLanguageDict.related_languages);
};
```

Comment: It is the dictionary key

Comment: Okay @VincentNguyen Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is, what is called a [Property accessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors).

`audioLanguageDict` is an object with (at least) the properties `id`, `text` and `related_languages`, these can be accessed using the `.`, or the `[]` operator:

```
return new AudioLanguage(
  audioLanguageDict.id,
  audioLanguageDict.text,
  audioLanguageDict.related_languages
);
```

is equal to

```
return new AudioLanguage(
  audioLanguageDict["id"],
  audioLanguageDict["text"],
  audioLanguageDict["related_languages"]
);
```

What these properties refer to is of course completely custom.

Answer (score 0):

In your class (AudioLanguageDictionary), you have id, text and related_languages variables. And your function passes a object which is belongs to your class and from that class you are creating a another class object (AudioLanguage) which has same variables. This way you have 2 object with same variables but different classes. Now probably with this object you can do some operations differ than first one.